# How does a razor page show a picture?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

There is a code on the razor page, like this,

```
<img src="Images/Tree.jpg"  asp-append-version="true" width="286" height="135" />
```

After run, the page can not display the picture, is there any wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Images` folder should be placed under `wwwroot`.

And try this code:

```
<img src="~/Images/Tree.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="286" height="135"/>
```

For more details,you can see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

If your `Images` static files are outside of the `wwwroot` folder, to serve these files and make it work as expected, you can try:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
//...

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});

//...
```

Then you can enter the URL to access it.

Comment: A correct answer but just to add a little bit of context this is not related to razor. It's about the web-app and the folder structure for this web-app. This is pure html

Comment: You can add more details about it.

Comment: @learner1,Has your problem been solved?Are there any other questions?

Comment: I want to shift the folder under the Pages folder or directly under the project.  How to modify the code? Thanks

Comment: can not find https://localhost:44301/Images/Tree.jpg As soon as I put the folder under the Page folder(default root), I got the prompt.